# Oracle Apex Interactive Report, Disable Column type link on row with 'Disable conditions'

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

Inquiring if there is a way to disable a link of a row based on a condition set.

for example I have and IR with column a and b, column b type is link, and column a holds the value that will be run in a select statement to determine if the link will be disabled or not.

ex.
col a value = 'new'
col b value = link

select colname .... where value ='new'

if colname = 'Yes' then

disable link in col b

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no Read-Only property for an IR in APEX. But there is a workaround.

In the interactive report query, you can create a virtual column for the link by specifying the Oracle Apex URL format for the page. For this type also, you need to specify the column as a link, but in the target, you can specify the column name as #MY_LINK#. The advantage of using this type is you can disable the link for specific rows based on a condition and can change the arguments too.

The step by step process on how to achieve this is described in the below blog post
https://www.foxinfotech.in/2020/07/oracle-apex-creating-link-column-in-interactive-report.html